# jQuery plugin Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery

Installing jQuery plugin for displaying cookie/privacy message in Bootstrap 4.

Plugin doesn't work with:

vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js  (/*! jQuery v3.4.1 */)

However it works with:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js

Console shows error on line "}(jQuery));" inside cookies.js

What am I missing here?

Comment: Whats the name of the plugin? Can you provide more details and show us some of your code?

Comment: https://github.com/ketanmistry/ihavecookies

sry I didnt think important!

Comment: I tested the plugin with `bootstrap 4` starter template and it bugs: the plugin doesn't support `bootstrap 4`. I would use another plugin that supports `bootstrap 4`. Try [this one](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Cookie-Consent-Notice-Bootstrap-4-cookieAlert.html).